# Hide Dev Express AplicationMenu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

I'm using Dev Express Ribbon Control to load different views in my WPF Application.
I would like to be able hide/close the Application Menu at run-time when I want, and let the view that needs to be displayed to fit all the size of the screen.

I tried something like this but it didn't work as expected :

```
this.ApplicationMenu.BackstageClosed += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.ApplicationMenu
                .GetType()
                .GetProperty("IsBackStageViewOpen")
                .SetValue(this.ApplicationMenu, false);
            };
```

Here's a image of the application, and I'm trying to hide the left Application menu when the view present in the right part is loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create an implicit style for the `RibbonControl` type. In this style, create a trigger for the `RibbonControl.ApplicationMenu` property and set the [`RibbonControl.ShowApplicationButton`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Ribbon.RibbonControl.ShowApplicationButton.property) property to `false` if the menu is empty.

Comment: The ApplicationMenu will never by empty, it will contain a BackstageViewControl that will contain BackstageTabItems. I just need somehow to hide the whole control, and to be able to show it when I want to.